# No support for CPU image access

Tags: arcore, xiaomi

I am looking to get an Android device to try ARCore development for the first time. I had my eyes on the **Pocophone** but in the list of compatible ARCore devices (https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) there is a comment for all **Xiaomi**'s devices that there is "**No support for CPU image access**".

I have found any information on what that means on how will limit me and affect me.

Can anybody explain this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using Mi 8 for development and realized that acquire Image function was not working properly.

ArCore Acquire Image

https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame#acquireCameraImage()

After reporting the issue it was tagged as a bug and now ArCore team has finally updated that Mi Phones are not capable of executing the function.

So if you are planning on Image Processing, saving image or any other operation that needs access to the image. Don't buy Pocophone !!

The other functionalities like tracking and light estimation work perfectly.

Comment: So, if I have an app that displays a 3D avatar in the real world and I want my users to take a photo of it and save it to their gallery, it will not work with Xiaomi phones? is there a workaround to this? Xiaomi has a huge market share and it's a pity to exclude them

Comment: Well it doesn't always return null but isn't reliable for applications requiring continuous image processing.  

And in case you are planning on taking the photo of 3D avatar then you don't need to access the CPU image.

Acquire Camera Image returns the CPU image without any rendering/drawables drawn on it.

You can still capture the screen. You might wanna check out the Video Recording sample in Sceneform.

[https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/videorecording]